# Required emulator which can access sqlite database and also can support laptop which does not support virtualization

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I am using Acer Aspire E1 -431 with intel B950 processor which does not support virtualization. I want emulators for testing my developed android app. Since i want to access the contents of sqlite database for my app , please help me in finding an emulator for the same. Thanks.

Comment: does the default emulator require virtualization?

Comment: let me ask a qualifying question..you cannot run vbox at all, right? I ask because if you can run that you can run x86 images via the genymotion emulator

Comment: yes default emulator requires virtualization @Vlad Matvienko

Comment: I think i can run vbox. Does genymotion emulator can access database as default emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/). It is easy to implement and very helpfull. You can browse your database via`chrome://inspect`. Even on unrooted device.

Comment: Can stetho be operated offline?

Answer (score 0):

For viewing the database structure you can use SQlite browser.

[enter link description here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Android have a powerful built-in database, it doesn't come with the best set of debugging tools. In fact, unless you have a rooted device, you can't even get the SQLite tables off your device without jumping through some hoops.  Fortunately, the Android emulator doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: The problem is my lap dont suppport default android emulator.